# laravel 5.2 search query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Here is the most recent problem I have ran into. I'm trying to implement search into my application and I know how to do it when it comes to searching your tables for keywords with `where('firstname', 'LIKE', %$search%)` and such. However, how would I go about narrowing down a search based on what criteria the user specifies. For exlample search for $keyword but also a $city and $pricePoint.

I'm just trying to figure out how to structure the query in php so that if user specifies the $keyword and the city it searches for that, and if user only specifies the $keyword, the city aspect of the query is not present.

Project is build on Laravel 5.2 and mysql database. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there are 3 criteria: $keyword, $city and $pricePoint. You can do:

```
$query = DB::table('users');
if (!empty($keyword)) {
    $query = $query->where('keyword', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
}
if (!empty($city)) {
    $query = $query->where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$city.'%');
}
if (!empty($pricePoint)) {
    $query = $query->where('pricePoint', 'LIKE', '%'.$pricePoint.'%');
}
$results = $query->get();
```

Then you can of course make something more generic by doing a list of criteria and iterating through them with a loop instead of adding another if conditions.

Comment: Worked like a charm! You saved me many more hours of frustration.

Comment: I don't want to seem like i'm asking for too much, but do you know how to not include the empty input fields into the url when you do a get method submit on a form for search?

Comment: You need to use JavaScript. You can see that post that gives a possible way to do it: http://www.billerickson.net/code/hide-empty-fields-get-form/

Comment: Thank you for the response and the help!

Comment: is it possible to use the example above with a Users Model instead of a DB::table('users');